# How to cast a JSONObjectMap into Map?

Tags: json, grails, groovy

The following example I derived from 
http://mrhaki.blogspot.de/2013/12/grails-goodness-rendering-partial.html

### Domain

```
class Book {
    String title
    Map    details
}
```

### Controller

```
@Transactional
class BookApiController extends RestfulController {

    static responseFormats = ['json', 'xml']

    BookApiController() {
        super(Book)
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional
    def save(Book bookInstance) {

        println "details: " + bookInstance.details.getClass().name

        bookInstance.save flush:true

        respond bookInstance
    }

}
```

### URLMappings

```
"/api/book"(resources: "bookApi")
```

When I'm using this curl invocation:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"title":"Grails in Action","details":{"isbn":"123456789"}}' http://localhost:8080/restpoint/api/book
```

### Grails throws the following exception:

```
details: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.bindingsource.JsonDataBindingSourceCreator$JsonObjectMap

| Error 2014-06-09 13:45:52,057 [http-bio-8080-exec-4] ERROR errors.GrailsExceptionResolver  - ClassCastException occurred when processing request: [POST] /restpoint/api/book
com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to java.lang.String. Stacktrace follows:
Message: com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive cannot be cast to java.lang.String
    Line | Method
->>   23 | $tt__save in sample.core.BookApiController
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    198 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    724 | run       in java.lang.Thread
```

I need the map property (here called 'details') in my Book domain this is precondition. 
A we can see it above the map is an instance of  **org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.binding.bindingsource.JsonDataBindingSourceCreator$JsonObjectMap**

How can I cast it into a map?

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

-markus

Comment: workaround can be to simply iterate: map.each{k,v-> targetMap[k] = map[k]}. value should be converted to primitive in this way. But if you need to support nested maps or properties with dots, it requires more code with recursion

Comment: Thanks @droggo for your response. I've thought there is a much better way to handle this because I've already implemented such a recursive workaround.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug, please report a JIRA issue at http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS

Comment: Issue (GRAILS-11485) is now reported.